# Echo override class or function for PHP?

Tags: php, class, methods, overriding, echo

I'm wondering if it's possible to override the echo command in PHP so that I could easily string replace new lines with nothing to compress the HTML drawn from the php process.
Something like:

```
class echo($SomeVar){echo str_replace('\n','',$SomeVar);}
```

I've got no idea how to override a method or class in PHP like I can do with objective-c for example.

I'd just like to "re-echo" every single echo command on the site and compress all the line breaks from my code.

Rather than create a new custom "echo2" method and re-edit the entire site I thought I'd try a simple patch for the real echo command in php first.

Anyone done this?

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16327709/ob-start-echos-strings-out-still it could help you

Comment: I'm trying not to edit the site code, except for overriding the method - But thanks I'll read up on the link provided.